# UISlider track image disappears when returning from a specific view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

### **Image 1**

[image: Image 1]

---

### **Image 2**

[image]

---

### **Image 3**

[image]

1. 1st image is the settings screen and everything behaves normally
   upon the first loading of this screen.
2. 2nd image is the policy
   screen which is pushed from the settings screen.
3. 3rd image upon returning from the policy screen back to the settings screen shows the UI Slider now doesn't show the track image. The behavior still works normally, but the track is just gone. It's a very mysterious bug to me. If I go to another screen in the app and then hit settings it works fine again, but when I come from the policy screen the track image is gone.

I am using the default UISlider. I am using xib files for the different screens.

**When the Policy Button is clicked...**

```
EditorialPolicyViewController *policyView;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    policyView = [[EditorialPolicyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditorialPolicyViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    policyView = [[EditorialPolicyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditorialPolicyViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:policyView animated:YES];
```

**ViewDidLoad** - setting up the uislider

```
NSString *textSize = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Text Size"];
float textSizeFloat = [textSize floatValue];
self.textSizeSlider.value = textSizeFloat;

[self.textSizeSlider setMaximumValue:16.0];
[self.textSizeSlider setMinimumValue:11.0];
```

Let me know if you have any other questions. I am out of ideas on how to solve this bug.

**UPDATE**
Found that the code below was "theming" the slider but when I removed it, it worked fine. What is a way i can keep the theme color and not get it to disappear?

```
   [[UISlider appearance] setThumbTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:75/255.0f blue:152/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
   [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:164/255.0f green:75.0f blue:25/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
   [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:204/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the well known bug in `SetMaximumTrackTintColor`.
Remove this line:

```
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:204/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

and your app will work fine.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! So Apple has to fix this?

Comment: Could tell us more about that bug ? It seems it disappeared in iOS9.

Answer (score 0):

you can move the appearance changes into the viewDidLoad: function.
this way the appearance changes will only happened once.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Appearance changes here
}
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that this is a known bug. But have found a way to work around it so that you can still keep your theming:

```
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:204/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

In UIViewController's where I use a slider, I set the maximumTrackTintColor in the viewDidLoad: method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _slider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UISlider appearance].maximumTrackTintColor;
}
```

This works for me, so I wanted to share!